# Count entries starting from 20 days interval from the current date - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, count

How I will construct query that will allow to count number of entries from the database which date is in the interval of 20 days, I mean current date minus 20 days to get exact 20 days, and return 0 if no record was found?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you just want to refer to the Date and Time function help:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

> select NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-05-13 14:41:20 |
+---------------------+

> select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 DAY);
+-----------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 DAY) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2014-04-23 14:41:13               |
+-----------------------------------+
```

You are probably looking for something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE datefield BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 DAY);
```

Comment: SELECT date,COUNT(*) 
FROM requests
WHERE date
BETWEEN  NOW() AND  DATE_ADD(NOW(), -20 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE


this what i've got, but i have an error says 
"...for the right syntax to use near '-20 DAY) GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4"? my field has a datatype date only.

Comment: Did you forget INTERVAL?

Comment: oh. Thanks. It works. 

Can I ask another question? How can i add dates that doesnt exists in the records but in the range of the interval and just return 0 to count()? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question... maybe you should accept this answer and post a new question?